# Lazy load the drop down items while scrolling in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

Please let me know on how to load the drop-down items in 'InputSelect' control of the blazor while scrolling.
I have 3000 drop down items. On the scroll, i want only the next 20 records only to be loaded on demand not all 3000 items at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Its a Virtualize component handling exactly what your after. However, as far as I'm aware of it's only available in .NET 5 RC1. You can try a .NET 5 RC1 build [here](https://github.com/dotnet/installer).

Comment: I am using .netstandard2.1 and it is not compatible with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization.Please find error details below. Error NU1202 Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web 5.0.0-rc.2.20475.17 is not compatible with netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1).

Comment: You need to either upgrade your project to NET 5 RC *, instructions can be found [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-5-release-candidate-1/) for RC1. Actually RC2 was just released see [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-5-release-candidate-2/)
Otherwise consider using another implementation compatible with your current project e.g. [this](https://github.com/SveNord/Sve-Blazor-InfiniteScroll).
By the way, a great resource for Blazor related goodies is the [awesome github](https://github.com/AdrienTorris/awesome-blazor)

Comment: Virtualize doesnt seem to work under <select> or <inputselect>